# ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash when trying to connect to redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm trying to get rails connect to redis by following [this tutorial](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html).
But I'm getting the following error when I try `$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)` or even just `Redis.new`. I've tried the new notation as well `(host: 'localhost',port: 6379)`. Redis works (ping-PONG test via redis-cli passes).

```
ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:65:in `[]'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:65:in `info'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:606:in `inspect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Config Details:
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
```

Comment: odd - nothing looks wrong to my eye.  You shouldn't even need those parameters as you're using defaults.  $redis = Redis.new() in the console gives you what error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I receive the same error using the redis gem version 2.1.1. Try to update the redis gem to latest, which is version 3.0.4.

To update the redis gem, you can either run

```
gem update redis
```

to update the locally installed version, or run

```
bundle update redis
```

to update the redis gem that is installed as part of your Gemfile.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p392 :001 > require 'redis'
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
from /Users/zachallett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:65:in `[]'
from /Users/zachallett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:65:in `info'
from /Users/zachallett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:606:in `inspect'
from /Users/zachallett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p392 :001 > require 'redis'
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
 => #<Redis client v3.0.4 for redis://localhost:6379/0>
```

Comment: I did the update, but it didn't work. (Meanwhile, I had also updated by ruby version using rvm). But this might seem interesting: 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > require 'redis'
 => false

Comment: Thanks! I had tried out gem update, but then it worked with bundle update/install!

Comment: If the OP needs redis gem 2.x, then upgrading to 2.2.x should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Had the following issue but we couldn't upgrade the redis gem to 3.x. It turned out that redis-rb was looking for a key/value pair for the redis config which didn't exist when running `redis-server`.

Running redis-server with the config file

```
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used redis yet, but based on a cursory look, seems like you're using the redis-ruby library. You probably want to experiment with redis-rails when it's available!(http://rubygems.org/gems/redis-rails)

The easiest way out is, look for Gemfile, and remove information about the redis gem. Replace that line with:

```
gem 'redis-rails'
```

Save the file, then run:

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: I had to use redis only. But this would have possibly worked.

Comment: This is misleading. redis-rails is only interesting if you want to use Redis as a cache or session store. Other than that, there's nothing to be integrated with a specific framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue, turns out `homebrew` had updated my `redis-server` from 2.6.x to 2.8.6

I reverted back to an older version of redis and it worked!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using 2.8. Also, update your redis gem to 2.2.x and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same error. The first thing I notices is that this error is related to the visual output that gets displayed in the console as a representation of the object. The `inspect` method is what gets called for this purpose. See the following from the stack trace:

`/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.1.1/lib/redis.rb:606:in 'inspect'`

So if you do `redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)`
or anytime you type just `redis` therafter, you'll get this error. However if you ignore it and just do
`redis.get 'foo'` everything works just fine.